# Search Office 2007 files with WSS 3.0

Tags: search, wss-3.0, windows-server

We have a Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 farm that consists of 4 servers:

- Admin Server
- Search Server
- Web Front End 1 (Load-Balanced)
- Web Front End 2 (Load-Balanced)

A user has reported that Office 2007 documents are not being indexed.  In troubleshooting the problem, I found these articles:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20109
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/946338/en-us?p=1&wa=wsignin1.0

When I look on our Admin Server and our Search Server, the Filter Packs have already been successfully installed, and the entries in the registry are correct.  When I look on the 2 web front end servers, they do NOT have the filter backs installed.

I'm attempting to take over some of the administrative responsibilities from people who have left the company.  I'm not sure if this is a new issue or if it has always been this way.

My question is - do the search filter packs need to be installed on the web front end servers?  Or is installing them on the admin and search servers adequate?  If the latter, what else could be causing this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Joan

Comment: did you check the Crawl logs, if their is any error? What is your crawl schedule, If you did not run a FUll crawl in last couple of month then run that and test it.

Comment: Thank you, Wagas, for your response.  We run a full crawl once per month and an incremental crawl daily.  There are some errors in our crawl log, but none are present for the site in question.

Comment: what file types they are not getting?

Comment: The issue was reported on an xslx file.  There is an entry for this type in the registry of both the admin and search servers.

Comment: can you search that file in crawl log( i am not sure if you can in wss 3.0, long time ago)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Where I am defining the crawl rules, do you want me to try to create a rule that will crawl just that file?

Comment: I see what you mean - I will see try to find it in the crawl log.

Comment: I found the document of interest in the crawl log - it has a green indicator and says it was crawled.  The same document was saved as an xls file and a search was done for a word that exists in both files.  The xls result was returned.  The xlsx resi;t was not.

Comment: the person who is performing the search should have atleast read permission on the file.

Comment: Yes, he does - he has Design access.  I am a site collection admin, and I get the same results when searching.  The xls doc is returned, but not the xlsx doc.

Comment: are you WFE are query servers?

Comment: I think your solution is filter pack should be on all server in the farm. As i remember it is part of pre-requisite for SharePoint 2010. SO make sure filter pack installed on your WFE.

Comment: The search services are not running on the WFE's, we have a separate server for that.  You are helping me to investigate this issue.  I found another xlsx file and a docx file in the crawl log, on this same site, and I was able to search for a term with those files successfully.  So it seems like this issue is not related to the filter packs, but something specific to this document.

Comment: my above response as i just go through the sp 2010 documentations and saw filter pack is part of the pre requisite. what i will suggest you in this case....May be delete the file and re add it.....or may be just make a copy and upload to different DL and then run the crawl and test it

Comment: Ok thank you, I will request that the user delete and re-upload this particular file.  Then I will kick off a full crawl and test to see if it gets returned.  And I will make a note that we will need the filter packs installed on ALL servers if we want to upgrade.  Thank you!

Comment: Great, please share the result here of the outcome...i am putting those troubleshooting steps in answer for community benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check.

- Run a Full crawl if not done before.
- Make sure the Search is crawling that document.You should check in the Crawl history /log if the specified file indexed.
- Check the crawl logs for potential error.
- Also try to upload the different 2007 files and run the full crawl and test it.

from communications, looks like your problem with a specific file. I would make a copy or delete and re-add it and then run full crawl and test it.

Note: On the side note, Filter Pack is prerequisite for SharePoint 2010, that's mean it should be install on all server in the farm. But no sure about wss3.0, because my experince is telling this is required only on search servers.